# how can add busy cursor to every event in application

Tags: java, swing

I am doing desktop application using swing and want busy cursor to every event
current using code

```
try {
     Cursor hourglassCursor = 
          Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR); this.setCursor(hourglassCursor);
     doProcessing();
} 
finally {
          Cursor normalCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
          this.setCursor(normalCursor);
        }
```

I want apply global function that apply on every event
Please help me

Comment: I am not an expert in Aspect Oriented Programming but I think it can do what you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: Why?  Every time you moved the mouse it would become a busy cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that sets Cursor to the Component

```
public void doProcessing(Component component, Runnable process){
  if (component==null || process==null){
    return;
  }
  component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
  try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(process);
  } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
}
```